# FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'in_out_put/live_data.csv'の対処方法を教えて下さい

Tags: python

anacondaのjupyternotebookでAIのプログラムをしていました。
以下の作業を読み込みをしていました所、エラーになり困っています。
プログラム経験が無い初心者です。
ご教示頂ければと思います。
よろしくお願い致します。

学習済みのAIを用いて現在の相場から今が買い時(上昇)か売り時(下落)かを予測

```py
#⑨各種ライブラリをインポートする
print("[ライブラリのインポート開始]")
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import tensorflow as tf
#from tensorflow.keras.models import load_model,Model
from keras.models import load_model,Model
print("[ライブラリのインポート完了]")
​
m_recent=24 #【要調整】予測に使う足の本数(過去の24本の足を元に予測する)
​
#⑩直近の値動きデータの準備
print("[直近の値動きデータ読み込み開始]")#読み込みの開始を表示
data = pd.read_csv("in_out_put/live_data.csv", encoding="shift-jis") #【要調整】直近の値動きデータを読み込む
data = data.loc[:, ["Low","Close","High"]] #行は全部（：）で、列は"Low","Close","High"の3つだけを抽出
X = []  #まずXの空箱を用意
print("[直近の値動きデータ読み込み完了]")#読み込みの完了を表示
​
print("[直近の値動きデータ構築開始]")#AIに入力するデータ構築の開始を表示
X.append(data.loc[len(data) - m_recent:(len(data)),["Low","Close","High"]]) #最終行から24行までの"Low","Close","High"の値をXに追加  
X_live = np.array(X) #numpy配列を生成
print(X_live) #X_liveを表示
print("[直近の値動きデータ構築完了]")#AIに入力するデータ構築の完了を表示
​
#⑪学習済みAIの読み込み
print("[学習済みAIの読み込み開始]")#学習済みAIの読み込み開始を表示
model = load_model('in_out_put/model_epochs_10.h5')#【要調整】保存された学習済みAIを読み込む
print("[学習済みAIの読み込み完了]")#学習済みAIの読み込み完了を表示
​
#⑫直近のデータを用いた予測の実行
print("[直近の値動きデータを用いた予測開始]")
predicted = model.predict(X_live) #X_liveを入力として予測を実行
print("[直近の値動きデータを用いた予測完了]")
​
#⑬予測結果の表示
print("================================================")#飾りの横線を表示
if predicted[0,0] >= 0.5:#上昇の確信度が50%以上の時
    print("予測結果：",'{:.4g}'.format(predicted[0,0]*100),"%の確率で上昇")#有効数字4桁→{:.4g}で確信度を表示
else:#下落の確信度が50%以上の時
    print("予測結果：",'{:.4g}'.format(predicted[0,1]*100),"%の確率で下落")#有効数字4桁→{:.4g}で確信度を表示
print("================================================")#飾りの横線を表示
```

出力

```
[ライブラリのインポート開始]
[ライブラリのインポート完了]
[直近の値動きデータ読み込み開始]
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-80fce524d42d> in <module>
     12 #⑩直近の値動きデータの準備
     13 print("[直近の値動きデータ読み込み開始]")#読み込みの開始を表示
---> 14 data = pd.read_csv("in_out_put/live_data.csv", encoding="shift-jis") #【要調整】直近の値動きデータを読み込む
     15 data = data.loc[:, ["Low","Close","High"]] #行は全部（：）で、列は"Low","Close","High"の3つだけを抽出
     16 X = []  #まずXの空箱を用意

~\anaconda3\envs\ai_aki_maki\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in read_csv(filepath_or_buffer, sep, delimiter, header, names, index_col, usecols, squeeze, prefix, mangle_dupe_cols, dtype, engine, converters, true_values, false_values, skipinitialspace, skiprows, skipfooter, nrows, na_values, keep_default_na, na_filter, verbose, skip_blank_lines, parse_dates, infer_datetime_format, keep_date_col, date_parser, dayfirst, cache_dates, iterator, chunksize, compression, thousands, decimal, lineterminator, quotechar, quoting, doublequote, escapechar, comment, encoding, dialect, error_bad_lines, warn_bad_lines, delim_whitespace, low_memory, memory_map, float_precision)
    686     )
    687 
--> 688     return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
    689 
    690 

~\anaconda3\envs\ai_aki_maki\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
    452 
    453     # Create the parser.
--> 454     parser = TextFileReader(fp_or_buf, **kwds)
    455 
    456     if chunksize or iterator:

~\anaconda3\envs\ai_aki_maki\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in __init__(self, f, engine, **kwds)
    946             self.options["has_index_names"] = kwds["has_index_names"]
    947 
--> 948         self._make_engine(self.engine)
    949 
    950     def close(self):

~\anaconda3\envs\ai_aki_maki\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in _make_engine(self, engine)
   1178     def _make_engine(self, engine="c"):
   1179         if engine == "c":
-> 1180             self._engine = CParserWrapper(self.f, **self.options)
   1181         else:
   1182             if engine == "python":

~\anaconda3\envs\ai_aki_maki\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in __init__(self, src, **kwds)
   1991         if kwds.get("compression") is None and encoding:
   1992             if isinstance(src, str):
-> 1993                 src = open(src, "rb")
   1994                 self.handles.append(src)
   1995 

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'in_out_put/live_data.csv'
'''
```

Comment: 'in_out_put/live_data.csv' というファイルが存在しない, メッセージ出てますね。Jupyter起動したディレクトリー以下に, そのようなファイルが見つからないようです

Comment: ファイルパスが間違っているのではないでしょうか？

Comment: 読んでいないかもしれないので補足です。回答内の**追記**部分に, デスクトップ以下にフォルダー＆ファイルが存在する場合のコード書いてます。

Answer (score 1):

ファイルの位置が不明の場合, 以下のようにして調べることが可能です

```py
from pathlib import Path

# カレントディレクトリー以下を探索 (たぶんそれなり時間かかるはず)
cur = Path('.')
for f in cur.glob('**/live_data.csv'):
    print(f)
```

あるいは homeディレクトリー以下から辿ることも

```py
from pathlib import Path

# homeディレクトリー以下を探索 (時間かかるはず)
home = Path.home()
for f in home.glob('**/live_data.csv'):
    print(f)
```

ディレクトリー位置が判明していて 最初に見つけたファイルを扱う例

```py
folder = cur / '何処かのディレクトリーパス' / 'in_out_put'

# 存在する場合に, 最初に見つけたファイルを取得
fname, = folder.glob('*.json')
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_json(fname, orient='index')
```

---

##### 追記

質問のコードのように `"in_out_put/live_data.csv"` だと, カレントディレクトリー内, で扱われます (この回答の最初のコードが「カレントディレクトリー以下」)

Desktopなら以下のように記述できる
(無駄にコード長めにしてるので ある程度省略可能)

```py
from pathlib import Path
desktop = Path.home()/ 'Desktop'
print(f'パス: {desktop}\t存在する？ {desktop.exists()}')

fname = desktop / 'in_out_put' / 'live_data.csv'
print(f'パス: {fname}\t存在する？ {fname.exists()}')

if fname.exists():
    df = pd.read_csv(fname, encoding="shift-jis")
    display(df)
```

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。
in_out_putというファイルはデスクトップに存在しています。
そのファイルの中にlive_data.csvが入っています。
表示の仕方が間違っているのでしょうか？
ご教示ください。
よろしくお願いします。

Comment: @AI_aki さん、ご質問者さんと同一の方でしたら、アカウントが 2 つに分かれてしまったようです。ヘルプページを参考に、アカウントを統合してみてください: https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts 。質問したアカウントであれば回答へ自由にコメントできます。